# R. Контрольные карты Шухарта

Tags: r

В пакетах qcc и qicharts2 есть функции, которые позволяют построить непосредственно график и проанализировать его. Если точка выходит за контрольные границы или же подвержена некой определенной зависимости, то она подсвечивается красным.(Как на картинке)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График мне не нужен, а нужны именно сами значения этих точек. Можно ли как-нибудь их получить отдельно от графика?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, с помощью которого вы получаете графики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> График мне не нужен, а нужны именно сами значения этих точек. Можно ли как-нибудь их получить отдельно от графика?

### их? - да, можно

---

```
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qcc/vignettes/qcc_a_quick_tour.html
# Between and within sample extra variation
library(qcc)
mu = 100
sigma_W = 10
epsilon = rnorm(120, sd=0.3)
W = c(-4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, -2) # assumed workers cycle
W = rep(rep(W, rep(5,8)), 3)
x = mu + W + sigma_W*epsilon
x = matrix(x, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
q = qcc(x, type="xbar")
#
# summary(q)
# with(q,summary(limits))
#
# print(q)
# with(q,print(limits))
#
# with(q,summary(data))
# with(q,summary(violations))
# print(q$violations)
print(q$violations$beyond.limits)#[1]  5  1  9 17

limitKeys = q$violations$beyond.limits
data = q$data

# print(limitKeys)

# print(data)
# print(as.vector(t(data)))
# print(length(data))

for(i in 1:length(limitKeys)){
    key = limitKeys[i]
    print(paste('--index',i,'key',key))
    arr = data[key,]
    print(arr)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Полезные функции](http://r-analytics.blogspot.ru/p/blog-page_06.html#.WrG26nVubDd)

Comment: Cпасибо, то что нужно!
Только теперь немного непонятно проверяет ли функция на другие критерии, кроме выхода за контрольные границы?

К примеру если 9 последовательных точек в зоне С?